# Using generics in interfaces and property

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a bunch of classes/interfaces for use in defining HTTP requests.

The `Request` class is defined as below

```
internal class Request : IRequest
{
    public Request(Uri uri, Method method, Headers headers)
    {
        Uri = uri;
        Method = method;
        Headers = Headers;
    }

    public IRequestBody Body { get; set; }
}
```

For `IRequestBody` I want to be able to define a Type, based on what the request is. For example, a request might contain JSON data, or Form Data.

I tried to define `IRequestBody` as

```
public interface IRequestBody<T>
{
    RequestBodyType Type { get; }

    T Payload { get; }
}
```

With the hope that I could then define classes such as:

```
public class FormDataRequestBody : IRequestBody<NameValueCollection>
{
    public RequestBodyType Type => RequestBodyType.FormData;

    public NameValueCollection Payload => new NameValueCollection();
}
```

However, on the `Request` class I must define the Type in the `Body` property definition. How can I make `Body` on the `Request` class generic so I can pass any instance of `IRequestBody` without knowing the Type upfront?

Comment: Isn't it just `IRequestBody<T>`? What is the problem when you define a generic type in the `Request` class and use it in the `Body` property?

Comment: You can make a non-generic version of `IRequestBody` and inherit it `IRequestBody<T>`, and still use `public IRequestBody Body { get; set; }` in `Request` class

Comment: What Pavel said is typical.  See `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` (which extends `IEnumerable`) for a canonical example.

Comment: Struggling to understand why you need a T at all; polymorphism seems to handle this   Your users will make a new FormDataRequestBody and use its methods to add data, you will have some method (or override tostring?) on your IRequestBody that turns the body into a string or stream for sending over the wire; every impl you make will have a need to call this same method to get the string but a different logic for creating it . What would you have done with your T Payload?

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, how can you have a ToString implementation without knowing the Type? T is there so I know what the Type is so I can write the various ToString overrides